# Merging from a VersionSpec in TFS: VersionSpec.Latest does not work as expected

Tags: version-control, tfs, tfs-sdk

I have created a utility in TFS to enumerate the changes and conflicts from a source branch to a target branch.  I would like to optionally include a `VersionSpec` for the source branch.  However, when I supply the default `VersionSpec` as shown below, I do not get what is expected.  I have used the GUI to do the merge and it shows 19 changes with zero conflicts.  But in the TFS API it tells me that there are no changes if I use a `VersionSpec` as shown.

```
VersionSpec spec = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("T", null)
mergeStatus = workspace.Merge(ServerSourcePath, ServerTargetPath, spec, null, LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full, MergeOptions.None);
//mergeStatus.noActionNeeded returns TRUE

//OK now try another method
spec = VersionSpec.Latest
mergeStatus = workspace.Merge(ServerSourcePath, ServerTargetPath, spec, null, LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full, MergeOptions.None);
//mergeStatus.noActionNeeded returns TRUE again

//But if I try using null instead of a VersionSpec....
mergeStatus = workspace.Merge(ServerSourcePath, ServerTargetPath, null, null, LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full, MergeOptions.None);
//mergeStatus.noActionNeeded returns FALSE, and I am able to see all 19 changes
```

So why is it that null works correctly here, but the other two methods do not?  While I do intend to use null for this scenario, the lack of reliability of the other method makes me suspect that I cannot trust the results of any `VersionSpec`, such as a `LabelVersionSpec`.  I believe I may already have seen some suspect results when testing this using the `LabelVersionSpec`, so I need to understand if there is a reason for the discrepancy that I need to account for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Microsoft's usual lack of thorough documentation I misunderstood the `fromVersion` and `toVersion` parameters to mean `sourceVersion` and `targetVersion` (merging "from" one branch "to" another branch), respectively, though I did wonder what would be the use case would be around having a `VersionSpec` in the target branch, since you would always be applying it to the Tip.  As it turns out, it seems that the `fromVersion` and `toVersion` are there to select a subset of changesets, so in the code above, the `VersionSpec` spec variable should be used in the `toVersion` argument, not a `fromVersion`.  `fromVersion = null` would imply that the merge should go back to the initial changeset in the branch (or the last recorded merge, presumably), whereas `toVersion = null` would imply that the merge should use everything up to the Tip/most recent changeset.

Updated code:

```
VersionSpec spec = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("T", null)
mergeStatus = workspace.Merge(ServerSourcePath, ServerTargetPath, null, spec, LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full, MergeOptions.None);
//mergeStatus.noActionNeeded returns FALSE

//OK now try another method
spec = VersionSpec.Latest
mergeStatus = workspace.Merge(ServerSourcePath, ServerTargetPath, null, spec, LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full, MergeOptions.None);
//mergeStatus.noActionNeeded returns FALSE again

//And if I try using null instead of a VersionSpec....
mergeStatus = workspace.Merge(ServerSourcePath, ServerTargetPath, null, null, LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full, MergeOptions.None);
//mergeStatus.noActionNeeded returns FALSE
```

Comment: Jessehouwing thanks for the quick edits.  Sometimes just asking the question rather than stewing on it forever is what is needed to shed some light.  Here's to StackOverflow!